# Whole disk image incremental save and restore

Tags: linux

I want to create a whole disk image and some incremental of them.
First I created a disk backup with

```
dd if=/dev/disk1 of=/Volumes/USBDrive/diskimage.img bs=1024k
```

and there is my problem: how can I create an incremental disk image of diskimage.img?

And how is the way back from the incremental image to a complete disk?

Answer (score 3):

`dd` isn't really designed for doing something like that. And trying to find a way to make `dd` do incrementals is probably a lot of effort that will end in disaster.

What you're asking about is called **snapshots**.

On Linux there are two main ways to get snapshots:

1. Use LVM
2. Use BtrFS

I would highly recommend using LVM because of its maturity over BtrFS. You should check your distribution's documentation on how it is recommended to set up LVM, or the [LVM HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/) on the Linux Documentation Project website.

Comment: There are also zfs (both fuse and ZoL) and ddsnap. Using LVM, if you want multiple snapshots, you'll have to use the new _thin provisioning_ support or the performance will get very poor after a few snapshots, and it's not much more mature than btrfs. I'm not sure why there's a `/linux` tag on this question as the `/dev/disk1` and `/Volume` suggests MacOS/X instead.

Comment: I didn't mention ZFS because it's non-trivial to use ZFS as a root filesystem for Linux. I actually had paragraphs in there referring to ZFS, but decided to take them out.